# Black sludge, black flakes after seasoning

Tags: oil, barbecue, seasoning-pans

I recently purchased a new infrared grill. It has stainless steel emitters and porcelain coated cast iron grates above the emitters.

The instructions said to season it. So I put vegetable oil all over the emitters like it advised. I completed tbe seasoning process and turned the grill off and let it be.

I came back to the grill the next day and there are black flakes on the grates and there is a black almost sludge on the emitters.its not completely covering them but it’s like little flakes of black super soft something and the sludge is like a gummy residue.

My question is: the porcelain isn’t like flaming/flaming off or anything right?

I was thinking maybe the heat got to high in the gril and turned the vegetable oil into sludge and than into paper flakes as some of it evaporated or burned off. I’m just scared to use the gril and was looking for some reassurance of what it is or what I should do. I don’t want to call the company and sound horribly stupid so I figure I would come ask you all and get roasted here instead.

My gut tells me it’s the oil and to just clean everything and we are good to go but if it’s defective and dangerous I would rather be safe than sorry.

Thanks [image][image]

Comment: How much oil did you put on? With seasoning cast iron/black steel/etc cookware, you really only need a very thin layer. Also, would you be able to share the user manual for your grill and/or a picture of the black flakes/sludge?

Comment: The cast iron is porcelain coated so it’s not truly cast iron. The emitter is stainless steel. That’s what they were having me season was the stainless steel emitter. I imagine I put too much on as well. I had a paper towel that I basically soaked in oil since the emitter is v snapped with tiny holes in it so I could get the oil all over it. I added a picture @LSchoon

Comment: Coated cast iron does not usually need to be seasoned. Neither does stainless steel, but it makes a little more sense in that case. Your updated question shows that you used _way_ too much oil; you really need the barest of coatings.

Comment: So I can just wash it all off and be good to go. I’m not going to hurt myself by using it right. I figure the temp got to high, broke down the oil, and some of the molecules that broke off in the oil chains burnt to a crisp and become like ash while the parts with no real boil point turned to sludge and just burnt into the ooze.

Comment: A good scrub and you'll be fine, yes.